# Draw circle arc with GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP

Tags: ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to write a method that will draw an arc from a start angle to an end angle using GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP. I've written the following code but have the following problems:

1. I can't seem to get the proper angles working. They seem offset from where they should be by an odd amount (not 90/45/180).
2. If the total angle between the two is more that 180 degrees then the arc will draw the smaller angle on the circle between the two. i.e if the total angle is 200 degrees it will draw an arc that is 160 degrees on the other part of the circle.

I've spent way to much time trying to get this right and figured it would be helpful to have another pair of eyes looking at my code. Image below shows the triangle strips I am trying to create between the angles. I'll be applying a texture after I figure this part out. Thanks for your help!

[image: triangle strips]

```
-(void) drawArcFrom:(CGFloat)startAngle to:(CGFloat)endAngle position:(CGFloat)position radius:(CGPoint)radius {

    CGFloat segmentWidth = 10.0;
    CGFloat increment = fabsf(endAngle - startAngle) / segmentWidth;
    int numSegs = fabsf(endAngle - startAngle) / segmentWidth;
    int direction = (endAngle - startAngle > 0) ? 1 : -1;

    ccVertex2F vertices[numSegs * 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < numSegs; i++) {
        CGFloat angle = startAngle - (i * increment * direction);
        CGPoint outsidePoint = ccpAdd(position, ccp(sinf(CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle)) * (radius + 4), cosf(CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle)) * (radius + 4)));
        CGPoint insidePoint = ccpAdd(position, ccp(sinf(CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle)) * (radius - 4), cosf(CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle)) * (radius - 4)));

        vertices[i * 2] = (ccVertex2F) {outsidePoint.x, outsidePoint.y };
        vertices[i * 2 + 1] = (ccVertex2F) {insidePoint.x, insidePoint.y };
    }

    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, (GLsizei) numSegs * 2);

}
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what it looks like? The idea looks mostly right. But you haven't included the definition of `angle1`. If you're not initializing it, it could explain the offset. For the other problem, you could always sort the angles before doing math on them. Make sure you always go from low to high, for example.

Comment: You were right. Making sure I started from the lowest angle and went to the higher angle was the main fix. Thanks for your suggestion. `angle1` was a typo and was actually supposed to be `startAngle` which I've changed.

Comment: ps: speed it up and make it easier to read by doing the deg2rad calculation once per angle instead of 4 times

Answer (score 2):

My code for android for full circle.
SEGMENTS  = 20;
coords [x,y,z]

```
    float w2 = width / 2f;
    float h2 = height / 2f;

    double radius = Math.min(w2, h2);
    double PI2 = Math.PI * 2d;
    coords = new float[SEGMENTS * 2 * 3];
    double angle;
    int index = 0;
    double min_radius = radius - circle_width;
    double max_radius = radius + circle_width;
    for (int i = 0; i < SEGMENTS; i++, index += 6) {
        angle = (PI2 * (double) i) / (double) (SEGMENTS - 1);
        double sin_angle = Math.sin(angle);
        double cos_angle = Math.cos(angle);
        coords[index + 0] = (float) (cos_angle * max_radius);
        coords[index + 1] = (float) (sin_angle * max_radius);
        coords[index + 2] = 0f;
        coords[index + 3] = (float) (cos_angle * min_radius);
        coords[index + 4] = (float) (sin_angle * min_radius);
        coords[index + 5] = 0f;
    }
```